# Flutter build_runner stopped generating .g files for a custom generator

Tags: flutter, annotations

Some time ago I wrote a generator for converting a model to XML and back that uses the `source_gen` and `build_runner` packages. It worked fine until yesterday, when the `dart run build_runner build` command stopped creating .g files in the folders, but only for this custom generator.

I use other third-party generators in my project, like ObjectBox or Dio, but for them the files are generated and put in the folders where they should be.

It creates files in .dart_tool/build/generated, even correctly generated, it just doesn't put them in project folders.

This is my custom generator build.yaml

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      generators|annotations:
        enabled: true

builders:
  generators:
    target: ':generators'
    import: 'package:generators/builder.dart'
    builder_factories: ['fromResponse', 'toRequest','toXmlPart']
    build_extensions: {'.dart': ['.g.dart'] }
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_to: cache
    applies_builders: ['source_gen|combining_builder']
```

This is the last part of verbose output from `dart run build_runner build` .
The build_runner notices the files, but doesnt put the .g files into the directories

```
[FINE] generators on lib/features/login/data/data_sources/loginApi.dart:Running ToXmlPartGenerator
[FINE] generators on lib/features/login/domain/entities/services/KACZZV1R1_request.dart:Running ToXmlPartGenerator
[FINE] generators on lib/features/login/domain/entities/services/KACZZV1R1_response.dart:Running ToXmlPartGenerator
[FINE] generators on lib/features/login/presentation/bloc/login_bloc.dart:Running ToXmlPartGenerator
[FINE] generators on lib/features/settings_screen/presentation/bloc/settings_bloc.dart:Running ToXmlPartGenerator
[INFO] Build:Running build completed, took 40.5s

[INFO] Build:Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Build:Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 92ms

[INFO] Build:Succeeded after 40.6s with 58 outputs (1651 actions)
```

This is my pubspec.yaml (i left only the packages I think might be relevant to this issue).

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path: ^1.8.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
  retrofit: any
  logger: any
  mocktail: ^0.3.0
  objectbox: ^2.0.0
  objectbox_flutter_libs: any
  annotations:
    path: ../annotations/
  analyzer: ^5.13.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.4.4
  retrofit_generator: any
  test:
  bloc_test: ^9.1.2
  generators:
    path: ../generators/
  objectbox_generator: 2.0.0
  json_serializable: ^6.7.0
```

I tried the following:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

- In the files themselves, I use `part 'file.g.dart'`
- Delete the .dart_tool/ folder
- *Invalidate caches and restart*
- Checking if the annotations are correctly used (it worked before with no problem)
- Running Android Studio as Administrator
- Checking the `dart run build_runner generate-build-script`. It shows the correct path to the project
- Updating to lastest version of Flutter

However, none of these worked.

I expect that the .g files are generated in the same folder